# Use event and delegate in subclass

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Why can't I use the event declared in `Base` from `Sub`?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sub sub = new Sub();
        sub.log += new Base.logEvent(sub_log);
        sub.go();
    }

    static void sub_log(string message, int level)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(message + " " + level);
    }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public delegate void logEvent(String message, int level);

    public event logEvent log;
}

public class Sub : Base
{

    public void go()
    {
        log("Test", 1); // <-- this won't compile
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756237/c-raising-an-inherited-event

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Events may only be invoked from the class that declares them.**

From outside of the definition of a class (even in a derived class) you can only register and unregister from an `event`. Inside of the class, the compiler only allows you to raise the event. This is a by-design behavior of C# (which actually changes slightly in C#4 - [Chris Burrows describes the changes on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=events+c%23+4)).

What you want to do here is provide a `RaiseLogEvent()` method in the base class, which would allow the derived class to invoke this event.

```
public abstract class Base
{ 
  public delegate void logEvent(String message, int level); 

  public event logEvent log; 

  protected void RaiseLogEvent( string msg, int level )
  {
      // note the idomatic use of the copy/test/invoke pattern...
      logEvent evt = log;
      if( evt != null )
      {
          evt( msg, level );
      }
  }
}
```

As an aside, you should consider using the `EventHandler<>` delegate type, rather than creating your own event types when possible.

Comment: So instead of declareing a delegate i make a subclass of EventArgs that holds my message and loglevel? Why is that better?

Comment: @klundy: The standard pattern for event handler in .NET is to supply a sender and a object representing the arguments. This allows subscribers of envents to retain consistency in their signatures, and reduces confusion about what parameters are expected. With C# 4's delegate co/contra-variance it becomes easier to write generic event handlers when the handler does not care about the arguments or sender. What I've done in many cases is to create a `EventArgs<TA,TB,...>` generic class that inherits from `EventArgs` and allows me to pass data to handlers ... but that's just a style choice.

Comment: This is one of the most useless, braindamaged, clueless bits of language design I've seen in a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Because events can only be called from the declaring class. Just create a method in the base class to call it:

```
protected virtual RaiseLogEvent(string s, int i)
{
  log(s, i);
}
```

So you can use it in deriving classes, and even override it.

On another note, I would strongly advise you to follow the design guidelines for events, and create an own EventArgs class, and use the `EventHandler<T>` delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can declare events in a base class so that they can also be raised from derived classes.

Create a protected invoking method for the event. By calling this invoking method, derived classes can invoke the event.

Read the standard way to do so here:
[How to raise base class events in derived classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx)