# c# event inheritance. Compile but throw an exception at runtime

Tags: c#, events, inheritance, event-handling

I've got a problem with an event rising. Here is my base class:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T>
{
  public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs<T>> MessageReceived;

  protected void OnMessageReceived(MyClass<T> sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs<T> e)
  {
    EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs<T>> handler = MessageReceived;

    if (MessageReceived != null)
      MessageReceived(sender, e);
  }
}
```

And my implementation :

```
public class MyDerivedClass: MyClass<string>
{
  void AFunction()
  {
    // Do some stuff
    OnMessageReceived(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs<string>("data"));
  }
```

When `OnMessageReceived` is called, the system throw a `System.ArgumentNullException` ("Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type"). I already read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648605/c-sharp-event-inheritance), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756237/c-raising-an-inherited-event) too, which help me to construct this code. But I can't find the reason of these exception (`sender` and `e` are not null, checked with the debugger).

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT** : Here's my `MessageReceivedEventArgs` implementation :

```
public class MessageReceivedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
  public T Data { get; private set; }

  public MessageReceivedEventArgs(T data)
  {
    Data = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add MessageReceivedEventArgs class in the code? The constructor of MessageReceivedEventArgs  should accept a string. Is it doing that? What compile time error are u getting?

Comment: @Rockstart I edited my post. The constructor accept T as it's generic. The compile time error is "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type". Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the Exception is thrown by your code? It could be possible that any of the event subscribers throws the Exception.

Event handling is a sequential operation. So if the first subscriber throws an unhandled exception the event handling will fail.

Edit: Have you had a look at the stacktrace. Also you could try to let the ide stop on every ArgumentNullException via the "Exception" window.

Comment: I feel so stupid... I was convinced that it was related to the generic type and the inheritance, and it was just as you said, a problem with a suscriber. My event rising was in a try-catch, and I didn't know that raising an event can throw an exception if one event subscribers call failed.
Thanks a lot Benjamin ! :D