# SelectedIndexChanged() event of a dropdownlist on a checkbobx checking

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a checkbox to indicate that communication address is same as the permanent address. There are 4 dropdownlists -

1. DRP_Comm_Country1
2. DRP_Comm_State1
3. DRP_Per_Country2
4. DRP_Per_State2

When i check the checkbox, the items of permanent address dropdownlists should be same as that of  communication address dropdownlists.How to make it possible?

My code is

```
protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DRP_Per_Country2.SelectedIndex = DRP_Comm_Country1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

But the `SelectedIndexChanged(`) Event of `DRP_Per_Country2` is not get fired.Is it a wrong method? If so ,how to work it?

Comment: DRP_Per_Country2.Text= DRP_Comm_Country1.Text;

Comment: @rapsalands...then DRP_Per_State2 will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to set the

```
AutoPostBack = true
```

property for all the `DropDownList`. If this wont work then call the `SelectedIndexChanged` Event manually

```
protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DRP_Per_Country2.SelectedIndex = DRP_Comm_Country1.SelectedIndex;
    DRP_Per_Country2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender,e);
}
```

This will surely fire the event.

Comment: @kishorejangid...let me try it

Comment: Its better to encapsulate the code within the indexchange as a method and call the method explicitly. IMO Event handlers should only be invoked as a consequence of an event. [Check burned finger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6545857/570150)