# create a generic event handler raising method when events are raising from subclasses

Tags: asp.net, events, generics, event-handling

I have a generic event raising method in my events class to be used with all events

```
    protected virtual void RaiseEvent<T>(EventHandler<T> eventToRaise, T eventArgs) where T : EventArgs
    {
        if (eventToRaise != null)
        {
            eventToRaise(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
```

but when I try to call this method from a subclass , I get an error that event can be used just on the left side of += or -= expression . is there any way to make this work ?

Update : one idea is to use enums . first define an enum of event names . then adding a dictionary that maps each enum value to its corresponding event . and finally in the method get the event and raise it based on what the parameter is . but I'm not sure how the dictionary should be ?

```
 public enum Events {Insert , Update , Delete};

dictionary<Events,EventHandler<T>> EventsDic = new dictionary<Events,EventHandler<T>>;

EventsDic.Add(Events.Insert,this.Insert);
```

is this correct ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Raising an inherited event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756237/c-raising-an-inherited-event)

Comment: Why would you catch an exception only to throw another one with *less information*?

Comment: @JonSkeet : good point , I don't know :) . thank you