# What does prefix "On" implement in event cases in C# coding?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, coding-style, msdn

I think there is quite a confusion over the usage of "On" as prefix of a C# method.

In MSDN article "Handling and Raising Event" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx it says,

> Typically, **to raise an event**, you add a method that is marked as
>   protected and virtual (in C#) or Protected and Overridable (in Visual
>   Basic). Name this method **OnEventName**; for example, OnDataReceived. The
>   method should take one parameter that specifies an event data object.
>   You provide this method to enable derived classes to override the
>   logic for raising the event. A derived class should always call the
>   OnEventName method of the base class to ensure that registered
>   delegates receive the event.

indicating the On... method is to raise an event. However, in many coding samples, even some provided by Microsoft, we can see event the On method used as event handler, like on in here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/tutorial--adding-move-look-controls-to-your-directx-game?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> First, let's populate the mouse and touch pointer **event handlers**. In
>   the first event handler, **OnPointerPressed**(), we get the x-y
>   coordinates of the pointer from the CoreWindow that manages our
>   display when the user clicks the mouse or touches the screen in the
>   look controller region.

```
void MoveLookController::OnPointerPressed(
_In_ CoreWindow^ sender,
_In_ PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    // Get the current pointer position.
    uint32 pointerID = args->CurrentPoint->PointerId;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 position = DirectX::XMFLOAT2( args->CurrentPoint->Position.X, args->CurrentPoint->Position.Y );

    auto device = args->CurrentPoint->PointerDevice;
    auto deviceType = device->PointerDeviceType;
    if ( deviceType == PointerDeviceType::Mouse )
    {
        // Action, Jump, or Fire
    }

    // Check  if this pointer is in the move control.
    // Change the values  to percentages of the preferred screen resolution.
    // You can set the x value to <preferred resolution> * <percentage of width>
    // for example, ( position.x < (screenResolution.x * 0.15) ).

    if (( position.x < 300 && position.y > 380 ) && ( deviceType != PointerDeviceType::Mouse ))
    {
        if ( !m_moveInUse ) // if no pointer is in this control yet
        {
            // Process a DPad touch down event.
            m_moveFirstDown = position;                 // Save the location of the initial contact.
            m_movePointerPosition = position;
            m_movePointerID = pointerID;                // Store the id of the pointer using this control.
            m_moveInUse = TRUE;
        }
    }
    else // This pointer must be in the look control.
    {
        if ( !m_lookInUse ) // If no pointer is in this control yet...
        {
            m_lookLastPoint = position;                         // save the point for later move
            m_lookPointerID = args->CurrentPoint->PointerId;  // store the id of pointer using this control
            m_lookLastDelta.x = m_lookLastDelta.y = 0;          // these are for smoothing
            m_lookInUse = TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

**My questions being:**

1. Is there indeed such ambiguity over the usage of "On" prefix or is it just my misunderstanding? Do people really use "On" in both **raising** and **handling** event methods?
2. What is the standard style of implementing the method **raising** and **handling** event? And what are the popular styles? What is the style that you suggest?

Comment: Though i personally think this is an interesting question, should this question be considered off-topic? As the description of the used tag "coding-style" already says, it is an entirely opinionated subject and this tag shouldn't be used anymore because it is off-topic. Because i'm unsure about that, i did not raise a flag, but i would like to see somebody explaining/elaborating that for me. Did not find anything useful one meta either. But http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be the right place for this question?

Comment: I believe this is a valid question, but the OP has confused a coding style and an idiomatic pattern. The former is subjective, the latter is not. Using protected virtual `OnEvenName` methods to raise events is indeed an idiomatic pattern and it should be followed (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/756237/11683 and/or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx). Now, naming event *handlers* (that are external to the event source) `OnEventName` would be more of coding style rather than a pattern, and it is a (slightly confusing) coincidence that they end up named the same.

Comment: You are quoting an article that doesn't use .NET *at all*.  So not exactly a great guide to use for .NET conventions.   It is also the event handler method, not the event and not the method that raises the event.  You already know the proper MSDN page, first link, so just use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the class that raises the event: when "some condition" occurs, it makes sense to call a method `OnSomeCondition()` in that class. Then if you want to inform an external party about about this condition, you'd have an event `SomeCondition` that you'd raise in the `OnSomeCondition()` method.

For the class that handles the event: when Visual Studio automatically generates a handler method, it calls it `someClass_SomeCondition` (at least in C#, which is what you've tagged your question). The second documentation exerpt and the example aren't C# though, which may explain the difference (I don't know if there's an "official" naming convention for event handlers).

However when you inherit from the class that raises the event, and the base class has followed the `protected virtual` recommendation, the word 'event' becomes ambiguous: you can still handle the `SomeCondition` event but you can also choose to override the `OnSomeCondition()` method.

So I wouldn't say that the `On` prefix "is used to raise an event", but "to handle a condition", and you can *choose* to raise an event in the `OnCondition()` method - and for the consuming side, you either *handle* an event or *override* the `OnCondition()` *behavior*. This is also what the first documentation exerpt says:

> You provide this method to enable derived classes to override the logic for raising the event.